# Переобразование из byte в double

Tags: c++-cli

```
double val = System::Convert::ToDouble(sim[5]);
```

sim[5]= 0xA7;  после конвертации дает значение -89
где ошибка, что я не учел?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0xA7 это 167 для беззнакового байта или -89 для знакового

Comment: Спасибо разобрался, изменил вопрос)

Comment: @PabloMurena Вы своей правкой радикально изменили суть вопроса. Если у Вас есть другой вопрос - задайте его

Comment: Просто я поменял, и в тот же момент вы ответили)